# Execute Python definition only if variable ==1

Tags: python

I wrote several definitions and I want the user to choose what definitions to run, but the definition always prints how can I turn on and of the definition?
if the user chooses 2 it should not print. what am I missing?

```
Senerio = 0
while Senerio not in (1, 2, 3, 4):
    Senerio = int(input("choose a commission/Aggregation senerio number \n"
                        "1. put in car \n"                     
                        "2. put in plane \n"
                        "3. put on boat \n"
                        "4. put on fire "))

if Senerio == 1:
Car = 1
Plane = 0
boat = 0
fire = 0

def incar():
    print('Im putting this in a car')
incar()

if car == 1:
    incar
```

Comment: This code as posted won't print anything. It just throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that wrapping my if statement around the definition gave me what I wanted
Like this:

```
if car == 1:
    def incar():
        print('Im putting this in a car')
    incar()
    incar
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it

```
Senerio = 0
while Senerio not in (1, 2, 3, 4):
    Senerio = int(input("choose a commission/Aggregation senerio number \n"
                        "1. put in car \n"                     
                        "2. put in plane \n"
                        "3. put on boat \n"
                        "4. put on fire "))

if Senerio == 1:
    car = 1
    plane = 0
    boat = 0
    fire = 0

def incar():
    print('Im putting this in a car')

if car == 1:
    incar()
```

Comment: I get it I missed the : in what I typed here but if the Senerio !=1 it is still print('I'm putting this in a car')